# Groupby month a pandas' dataframe based on a date column

Tags: pandas, date, datetime

I have a datafarme with a few lines listed below. I wanted to group the dataframe by month on the column labeled Date which spans from 1/1/1970 to 1/1/2011. Then compute some statistics for each month. The date column is datetime.datetime type. I used the following w/o success.

```
DataFrame.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='M')
```

I converted the datetime.datetime to Timestamp and tried DatetimeIndex but neither worked.

But i got the following error "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'"

```
    Date        Name   Time     I   D       Pre   Height
1    2011-01-01  OldFathful   9.55  01:39:00     4:15  09:41:00   130.0
2    2011-01-01  OldFathful  11.33  01:38:00     3:59  11:20:00   130.0
3    2011-01-01  OldFathful  13:00  01:27:00     4:00  13:00:00   140.0
4    2011-01-01  OldFathful  14:42  01:42:00     3:44  14:29:00   150.0
5    2011-01-01  OldFathful  16:08  01:26:00     4:00  16:02:00   140.0
```

Thanks in advance

EK

Comment: It's working for me after -> `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`

Comment: Thanks Nk03; but i wanted to group the datafarme of 81000 rows so that the dateframe will be grouped by month where i can aggregate some statistics on each month